# Scheme's Application-procedure error in function-call

Tags: function, scheme, procedure

I'm new to Scheme, and have to program the well-known 'merge-function' of two lists. While I understand the algorithm, I have been getting this error over and over again:

```
**merge((list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6))**
<procedure:merge>
. . application: not a procedure;
expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
given: (1 2 3)  arguments...:(4 5 6)
```

I thought my code was wrong, so I kept debugging it..changing into a dummy function to see if it still would react the same. It did.

```
#lang scheme

(define (merge list1 list2)

  (cond ((null? list1)list2)

    ((null? list2)list1)

    (else

    "Nothing more to do!"

    )
   )
)
```

The syntax check turned out nothing "wrong". I also read the answers to similar problems, but I can't just figure it out. The only option left, is that I'm making a wrong function call whilst not understanding why.

Looking forward to your feedback..

Comment: Thank you Oscar, it now works all well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how you're trying to call the procedure. Instead of this:

```
merge((list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6))
```

Try this, the correct way. Notice where the parentheses must go:

```
(merge (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6))
```